# Any wrapping viewgroup?

Tags: android, layout

I am looking for Wrappable ViewGroup just like what TextView do. I need this for layout. This should be something like LinearLayout but wrappable to multiple lines. Or do I need something custom?

Answer (score 0):

There is no layout manager in Android today that behaves like Swing's `FlowLayout`, where it wraps widgets onto multiple lines. It is theoretically possible for you to write one yourself, by looking at the open source code for `LinearLayout`, etc. and following the patterns they establish.

Sorry!