# List of images that wraps

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout with fixed view. I dynamically inject images in it (ImageViews) but I dunno in advance how many of them will be inserted. I'd like to have a layout where images wrap and go to a new line authomatically when they exceed the available width of the father (LinearLayout)

how do you recommend I should move?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Define a Listview within the Linear Layout like below. Wrap your Linear Layout tags around it.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
/>
```

Update this list view dynamically as you add images. This will solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

As I answered on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711581/any-wrapping-viewgroup) asked a couple of hours before yours:

There is no layout manager in Android today that behaves like Swing's `FlowLayout`, where it wraps widgets onto multiple lines. It is theoretically possible for you to write one yourself, by looking at the open source code for `LinearLayout`, etc. and following the patterns they establish.

Sorry!